# relation does not exist

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django, heroku

3-й день мучаюсь с данной проблемой. На heroku имеется БД MySQL. Также я создал django приложение, которое подключается к данной БД. Если я запускаю его у себя на компьютере, то у меня все работает. Однако если я запущу приложение на heroku, то у меня появляется ошибка:

> relation "station" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ongitude", "station"."Type", "station"."Link" FROM "station"

Ощущение будто приложение вообще не видит таблицы БД. Как исправить данную проблему?

**Вот полный Traceback:**

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "station" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ongitude", "station"."Type", "station"."Link" FROM "station"
                                                              ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/task1/views.py" in get
  45.         for station in stations:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  272.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1063.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /map/
Exception Value: relation "station" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ongitude", "station"."Type", "station"."Link" FROM "station"
                                                          ^
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#o032sw#v+_uj&f+a*&n*rz0l@4jyfn%^lub4t=itn%fdaxpni'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'task1',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'geomagnet.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'geomagnet.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'heroku_8165878e13ba965',
        'USER': 'be45b00e00ae8e',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Station, Net, Networkstations
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
import json
class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'station_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        stations = Station.objects.all()
        list_name_net = []
        stations_out = []

        for station in stations:
            list_name_net.append(
                list(Networkstations.objects.filter(idstation=station.id).values_list('idnet__name', flat=True)))

        for station in stations:
            stations_out.append(
                {'sitecode': station.sitecode, 'name': station.name, 'latitude': station.latitude,
                 'longitude': station.longitude, 'type': station.type, 'link': station.link, })
        ctx = {
            'stations': json.dumps(stations_out, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
            'list_name_net': json.dumps(list_name_net, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

**procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn geomagnet.wsgi --log-file -
```

**.gitignore:**

```
__pycache__/
*.pyc
```

**requerements.txt:**

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
mysqlclient==1.3.13
pytz==2019.1
whitenoise==3.3.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.1.
```

Comment: Судя по документации к heroku надо перейти на другую базу, либо использовать аддоны https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/data-management

Comment: @super16 я использую аддон ClearDB, который предназначен для БД MySQL. Используя аддон cleardb я создал БД MySQL.

Comment: А внутри heroku делали миграции? `heroku run python manage.py migrate` и `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @super16 да делал